# Keyboard shortcut for moving mouse to focused window?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

Is there a keyboard shortcut, or a setting, to make the mouse cursor "jump" to the currently focused window?

I use a dual monitor setup, and after <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>-ing to a window on the adjacent screen, it would be rather helpful to jump the mouse cursor to the center of it (sort of a like a reverse focus follow).

Comment: Start a window move with the keyboard and then press Esc.

Comment: Alt-Space then M?

Comment: I think your best shot is autohotkey. Write two keyboard bindings that each move the mouse cursor to the center of screen 1/2.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Alt-Space, M (or S) doesn't work if window is full screen.

Comment: @TNierath Is AutoHotKey known to interfear with Visual Studio?

Comment: I don't know, why? At it's core it's just a scripting language specialized for generating sequences of win32 messages and binding these to keys.

Comment: http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=16997.0

Comment: similar question: https://superuser.com/q/1374974/863212

Answer (score 4):

I came over the same problem and developed a small piece of software to help. I published it on the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/de-at/p/mousepointerreposition/9ncz1p9hpwfh?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
or you can download the source code [here](https://github.com/rhinterndorfer/MousePointerReposition) and compile it yourself.

The software runs in background and listens for certain keyboard input (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Win[+Shift]</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys, 2x<kbd>CTRL</kbd>) and will place the mouse cursor in the center of a active foreground window after all keys are released.

Feedback would be nice so I can try to improve.

Answer (score 4):

It took me a long time to find a solution, but even after one hour or so I did not find a working shortcut/software to bring my mouse pointer to another screen.

Most of the tools out there were not working on Windows 10 and i did not like to install some macro-tools and try some selfmade scripts.
The solution mentioned above called "MousePointerReposition" is really worth it.

So if you are working on a PC with 2 Screens (or more) you should give it a try.

I am using a Stream Deck Device ([Shortcuts to move Windows quickly between 2 Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BmPn.jpg)) to quickly move windows up and down between my 2 screens (using SHIFT+WIN+RIGHT) and togehter with MousePointerReposition it works like a charm.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Super User way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are two options available which can help to a limit if not everything you need.

you can control mouse cursor using numeric pad. Under "Ease of access center", you can find setting related to mouse. Turn on "Mouse Keys" to control mouse cursor.

[image]

You can also set mouse cursor to jump to default button of screen. Use mouse properties to do that.

[image]